# Executor stop all running tasks and run again

Tags: java, multithreading

i want to stop all tasks in my ExecutorService.

Now i try that :

```
    mExecutor.shutdownNow();
    // Prepare Scroller data
    mExecutor.execute(new Scroller(destination, speed));
```

But i catch exception

```
F/RH2.C.AndroidRuntime(20514): java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task ### rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@425a3ab0[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
F/RH2.C.AndroidRuntime(20514):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1979)
F/RH2.C.AndroidRuntime(20514):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:786)
F/RH2.C.AndroidRuntime(20514):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1307)
F/RH2.C.AndroidRuntime(20514):  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.execute(Executors.java:552)
```

How i can fix that? 
**P.S.** My multithreading knowledge is so low, so i will be pleasure if you explain me why i have that exception. Thanks.

Comment: You have shut it down, what would you expect? Have you read the Javodoc on `shutdownNow`, and on `ExecutorService` in general?

Comment: I expect that i can to run task again:) I say - my multithreading skills is low so i want to know right solution.

Comment: Are your documentation-reading skills also low? That's quite a showstopper for your intended career, let me tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mExecutor.shutdownNow();
// Prepare Scroller data
mExecutor =  Executors.newCachedThreadPool();//or other pool which u need

mExecutor.execute(new Scroller(destination, speed));
By this way u can go.
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have called the `shutdownNow()` method on Executor.

You can't submit any new Runnable/Thread instance to it. If you will try to do so, it will give you this exception.

Comment: So what i will to do?

Comment: I don't know your requirement exactly. But if you want to keep on submitting new task to your executor, you shouldn't call the `shutdown()` method on executor.

Answer (score 0):

RejectedExecutionException gets when you try to submit a Job/Task when executor has been already shutdown. 
To Fix the problem you have to make sure your Executor is up and running condition.
Before submitting the job check Executor is running.

```
mExecutor.shutdownNow();
// Prepare Scroller data
if(mExecutor == null || mExecutor.isShutdown()) {
  //whatever your executor type is, create new instance is its shutdown already
  mExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
}
mExecutor.execute(new Scroller(destination, speed));
```

For further details you can check this link which has some sample code:
http://handling-thread.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/pause-and-resume-thread.html